# Understanding jQuery (basic question)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jscrollpane

i have a pretty basic jquery question. im trying to add jscrollpane to my site and get it to initialize after an ajax call. however when i run the function i keep getting the message "testFunction is not defined" in the console. the code is very basic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
      showArrows:true,
      maintainPosition: false
    }).data('jsp');

  function testFunction() {
      api.getContentPane().load('ajax_content.html', function() {
      api.reinitialise();
   });
 }          
});
```

why do i keep getting the message? if i take the testfunction out of the document ready function i get the error "api not defined" thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the scope of the variable `api` that you are defining. You need to define the `api` variable outside of the `$(document).ready(function() { ...`. Try this:

```
var api;
$(document).ready(function() {
  api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
      showArrows:true,
      maintainPosition: false
  }).data('jsp');
});

function testFunction() {
    api.getContentPane().load('ajax_content.html', function() {
        api.reinitialise();
    });
}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is because the scope of the test function is now the anonymous function you call on document ready. Declare testFunction outside that anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

The 'not defined' message is coming from code that is using testFunction but is not waiting until it is defined.  You have enclosed the definition of testFunction in the documentReady event but not the user of testFunction.